# Get current width and height of an Embed Clutter Stage

Tags: c, gtk, clutter, clutter-gui

I'm using Clutter to compose an interactive/animate UI. 
I'm using two box containers (ClutterBox) with an integrated FixedLayout, and I want to be able to rearrange those boxes onto screen using an hard-coded layout during (gtk-)window resizing. Searching in some gtk3 examples, I find out this can be achieved connecting the signal "size-allocate" of the GtkWindow.
 What I still unable to accomplish is to get  width and height of the Embed ClutterStage.

I used `gtk_widget_get_preferred_size` passing the ClutterStage widget, but it gives back to me only the preferred size, and not the current, resized value.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `clutter_actor_get_size()` on the stage returned by a `GtkClutterEmbed` widget is enough to get the size of the stage: the `GtkClutterEmbed` widget that owns the embedded stage resizes the stage every time GTK+ negotiates the geometry of the widgets of a window.

you can also use a `ClutterBindConstraint` object to bind the size of an actor to the size of the stage, or a `ClutterSnapConstraint` or a `ClutterAlignConstraint` objects to resize or align actors to the stage.

Answer (score 2):

Try `gtk_widget_get_allocation()`.